# Get access to httponly cookies with canopy

Tags: cookies, f#, canopy-web-testing

I need to clean session cookies during [canopy](http://lefthandedgoat.github.io/canopy/index.html) tests. I dont see any way to do it documentation.
Currently I managed to get to `core.browser.Manage().Cookies` which is a `OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.RemoteCookieJar` But I dont know how to remove the cookie using it.
Also, reading cookie values for httponly cookies is also someting I need to do.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

canopy is just a wrapper on top of Selenium Webdriver.  You can access the current browser/driver with browser or core.browser like you show above.

I believe that this should work for your first problem:

```
browser.Manage().Cookies.DeleteAllCookies()
```

For your second question, this should give you a string list of values for non secure cookies

```
let httpCookieValues = 
    browser.Manage().Cookies.AllCookies
    |> List.ofSeq
    |> List.filter (fun cookie -> not cookie.Secure)
    |> List.map (fun cookie -> cookie.Value)
```